# Vue Component not mounting in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I know this question has been asked a million times, but I haven't found a solution that works for me. I have absolutely no experience in Vue and after running `npm audit fix` it seems that my `vue-template-compiler` was updated forcing me to update my Vue package, both are `"^2.5.21"`. After doing so I get an error saying:

```
   app.js:37130 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <ExampleComponent
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong if anything. I've only added some content in the Example component shown here:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 visible-md visible-lg">
        <h5 id="quote"></h5>
        <h6 id="author"></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    const quote = document.getElementById("quote");
    const author = document.getElementById("author");

    let quoteArray = [
    ];

    let authorArray = [
    ];


    quote.innerHTML = "[ " + quoteBody + " ]";
    author.innerHTML = "- " + quoteAuthor;
  }
};
</script>
```

And here is my `app.js`:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key)))

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Here is where I am calling the Vue `ExampleComponent`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <example-component></example-component>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49139332/4171578 and see if it helps?

Comment: Post your HTML where you're calling the component.

Comment: Please show us where are you using the component. Maybe you are calling <ExampleComponent... instead <example-component....

Comment: I have added the HTML where I am calling the example component. Thank you everyone

Comment: @Amade adding the `.default`  did fix the issue. Strange, I guess they made that change in the newer version of Vue?